# C++11, move semantics of returning vectors functional style

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming, move-semantics

I'm creating an example to try to understand how the move semantics is optimized when using c++11.

First, I have the following two functions that take some input and return a modified version of the input.

```
std::vector<float> abs(const std::vector<float> &v)
{
  std::vector<float> abs_vec = v;

  for (auto &val: abs_vec) {
    auto i = &val - &abs_vec[0];
    abs_vec[i] = std::abs(abs_vec[i]);
  }

  return abs_vec;
}

std::vector<float> normalize(const std::vector<float> &v)
{
  std::vector<float> norm_vec = v;

  auto max_val = std::max_element(std::begin(norm_vec), std::end(norm_vec));
  auto min_val = std::min_element(std::begin(norm_vec), std::end(norm_vec));
  auto norm_factor = *max_val;
  auto min_check = std::abs(*min_val);

  if (min_check > std::abs(norm_factor)) {
    norm_factor = min_check;
  }

  for (auto &val: norm_vec) {
    auto i = &val - &norm_vec[0];
    norm_vec[i] = norm_vec[i] / norm_factor;
  }

  return norm_vec;
}
```

Then I test the function with the following code:

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<float> tmp{-1,2,-3,4,5};

  printf("pointer before: %p\n", &tmp[0]);
  tmp = normalize(tmp);
  printf("pointer after normalize: %p\n", &tmp[0]);
  tmp = abs(tmp);
  printf("pointer after abs: %p\n", &tmp[0]);

};
```

From this I get the output:

```
pointer before: 0x156dc20
pointer after normalize: 0x156e050
pointer after abs: 0x156dc20
```

Could anyone please explain what is going on and why it seems like I get a copy after normalization, but then the same memory location as the original after the abs function call?

Is there a better way to write functions in a functional style like this that would lead to more optimized code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why the memory address of the first element is the same after calling `abs()`, but there is a better way to write it. The code would be simpler if you use `std::transform()`, available in the `algorithm` header:

```
std::vector<float> abs(const std::vector<float> &v)
{
    std::vector<float> abs_vec;

    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(abs_vec),
                   [] (float val) {
        return std::abs(val);
    });

    return abs_vec;
}
```

This will iterate over all of the elements in `v`, and for each one will call the lambda function. The return value of that function will be inserted onto the end of `abs_vec`.

The loop at the end of `normalize()` could also be rewritten to use `std::transform()`, as well. In this case, the `norm_factor` variable can be captured so it can be used within the lambda:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(norm_vec),
               [norm_factor] (float val) {
    return val / norm_factor;
});
```

Comment: Would this invoke a move of the memory automatically, since I'm returning it to the same variable as was input?

Comment: Also, for the second example the norm_factor is a second argument for the lambda function. Could you give an example of how this can be implemented?

Comment: @toeplitz Yes, the vector will be moved and not copied when the function returns. C++11 states that if a type has a move constructor (which `std::vector` does), the copy can be elided and the actual value will be returned instead of invoking a copy.

Answer (score 3):

When you make a new copy from a const-reference that can't be a move, obviously. If you want to write these functions in a way where the vector gets moved in and out of them, you need to transfer the vectors by value (should be preferred here) or rvalue-reference, and move the vector into the function.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

std::vector<float> plus_five(std::vector<float> v)
{
    for (auto& e : v)
        e += 5;

    return v;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> v{1, 2, 3, 4};

    std::printf("%p\n", v.data());
    v = plus_five(std::move(v)); // move
    std::printf("%p\n", v.data());
    v = plus_five(v); // copy
    std::printf("%p\n", v.data());
}
```

Comment: In an attempt to use a more functional programming style, is this the recommended approach for these types of functions? Assuming the vector is very large, will this be a worthwhile optimization in compared to not using move and sticking with the const and copy?

Comment: @toeplitz:  Yes, this is the recommended way.  This answer avoids *all* copies (except where it explicitly copies as noted by the comment).  If you use this style in your example you will get the same address every time.

Answer (score 2):

The value you `printf` is the address of the underlying data member of the vector.

So I suppose that, in your case

1) the creation of `tmp` create (allocate) a data member in position 0x156dc20

2) the `normalize()` operation substitute the data member with the data member of the vector created in `normalize()` (`norm_vec`), with address 0x156e050, and free the memory of the previous data member

3) the `abs()` operation substitute the data member with the data member of the `vector` created in `abs()` (`abs_vec`), that is again 0x156dc20, recycling the previously freed memory

Briefly: I suppose that `abs_vect` recycle the memory previously used by `tmp`

En passant, your for-each loop are over-complicated.

The loop

```
for (auto &val: norm_vec) {
  auto i = &val - &norm_vec[0];
  norm_vec[i] = norm_vec[i] / norm_factor;
}
```

can be simplified (you're using a reference (`&`)) as

```
for (auto &val: norm_vec)
  val /= norm_factor;
```

and the loop

```
for (auto &val: abs_vec) {
  auto i = &val - &abs_vec[0];
  abs_vec[i] = std::abs(abs_vec[i]);
}
```

can be simplified (same reason) as

```
for (auto &val: abs_vec)
  val = std::abs(val);
```

The use of `std::transform`, as suggested by Andy, is (IMHO) even better.

Regarding the finding of `norm_factor`, i think that

```
auto pairIt = std::minmax_element(norm_vec.begin(), norm_vec.end());
auto norm_factor = std::max(std::abs(*(pairIt.first)), *(pairIt.second));
```

is simpler (and more optimized, I suppose) than

```
auto max_val = std::max_element(std::begin(norm_vec), std::end(norm_vec));
auto min_val = std::min_element(std::begin(norm_vec), std::end(norm_vec));
auto norm_factor = *max_val;
auto min_check = std::abs(*min_val);

if (min_check > std::abs(norm_factor)) {
  norm_factor = min_check;
}
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English